# Expression type `String` is ambiguous without more context?

Tags: swift, string, swift-playground

The following code in the Swift Playgrounds app for iPad gives me an error message:

```
Expression type `String` is ambiguous without more context
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var progress: Double = 0.6
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("test")
            HStack {
                Slider(value: $progress)
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", progress))
            }
        }.border(Color.blue)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

[image: compiler error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is odd. For some reason the Swift Playgrounds on the iPad is different.

Use String interpolation with a specifier instead:

Replace

```
Text(String(format: "%.2f", progress))
```

With

```
Text("\(progress, specifier: "%.2f")")
```

---

**Note:**

If you don't want your text jumping around, use a font with mono spaced digits such as *Helvetica Neue*.  Add `.font(Font.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 20))` to the end of your `Text` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have more information about the "string interpolation with a specifier" thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code... restart Xcode

[image]

Comment: That's wierd, but I was not using Xcode, it was the iPad app for Swift Playgrounds (version 3.3.1) that I was using. Have you tried the iPad app?